# What design limitations does a higher-than-average resistance trace impose?

Tags: pcb, trace

There's a [Kickstarter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickstarter) running right now for a machine that prints circuit boards. Rather than a traditional etching process, they use conductive (silver-based) ink to print traces and pads. It has a resistance of 12 m\$\Omega\$/in^2. What design limitations does this impose? More specifically, what kinds of circuits would I *not* be able to produce with these parameters?

I assume high frequency things like high speed busses ([LVDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling)?) and printed antennas? Other things?

*Note: I am specifically not placing a link to the project here as this question isn't meant as an advertisement for it.*

Comment: +1 for thinking to look at this parameter I was thinking of buying one this morning just to play with :)

Comment: Should your title say *resistance* (or maybe *resistivity*) instead of *reactance*? If you really mean reactance, could you edit the question to be more clear about how the machine makes traces with higher reactance?

Comment: @ThePhoton you're right. I meant to encompass both resistance and inductance, but worded wrong.

Comment: The inductance shouldn't be any worse than for an etched PCB. It comes from trace geometry and the separation from the return path.

Comment: Just get a voxel8 one, they support 3d printing of traces ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1/2 oz copper (about the lightest typically used) has a resistance of approximately 1m\$\Omega\$/\$\square\$, so it's more than an order of magnitude worse, and about 50x worse than the 2-oz copper typically used for power circuits.

You'd have to take that into account for power circuits, for analog circuits and for digital circuits that draw a lot of power. If you're just flashing LEDs with a microcontroller.. maybe okay. A 10 mil trace 3" long would have a resistance of 3.6 ohms, so at 50mA it would drop almost 0.2V.

Comment: On all browsers I can currently access this shows "1mΩ/[]" (some square box). I guess you used some rather new utf8 char there, maybe you can replace it by some inline latex?

Comment: @PlasmaHH The units of [sheet resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_resistance) are ohms per square so I used the empty square box.. \square in LaTex. The Wiki page I linked uses \Box which is very similar.